# shell script to create libre office Impress with images

Tags: bash, shell, automation, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I've some image files generated by an analysis. Every time I do analysis, the file names are same. And I've to create a presentation, and I'm using Libre Office Impress. 
Let us say, I've three images image1.png, image2.png, and image3.png, and I should put these images say in page no 3, page no 5, and page no 8

Now, I'm inserting images manually. I know very basic shell scripting. So I was wondering what would be the bash shell script to automatically create an libre office impress file with images automatically inserted at pages mentioned as above.

Comment: Shell scripts isn't for everything. That's all I can tell you here.

Comment: True. But it can call other programs which can do the jobs partly...  The idea is that we can connect two independent programs..

Comment: Find a CLI project that write whatever file format you want. This has little to do with any shell, less bash.

Answer (score 2):

If the main part of the .odp file doesn't change, it is possible to make a template in *flat openDocument* format, where the names of the 3 images are updated by script.
A *flat document* is a uncompressed **xml** document that can be open with a text editor to change some part manually **with caution**. Usually the name of such a document is rather with the `.fodp` You must save this template in flat format, with links to the images rather than incorporate them.

So.
Let us say :

- the template is at `/path/to/the/template.fodp` beside the images *im1.png*, *img2.png*, *img3.png* of the example.
- the name of the first image is `image1.png`, the second `image2.png`, and the third : `image3.png`.
- the images to be imported are in the same directory `/path/to/the/document` where will be the final document.

Let us write a script *insertImages.sh*

```
myTpl="$1" # will contains '/path/to/the/template.fodp'
myDir="$2" # will contains '/path/to/the/document'
img1="$3"  # will contains the name of the first image in myDir
img2="$4"  # will contains the name of the second image in myDir
img3="$5"  # will contains the name of the third image in myDir

[[ -f "$1" ]] && cp "$1" "$2/document.fodp" || exit 1 # checks if the template exists and copy it
[[ -f "$3" ]] && sed "$2/document.fodp" "s/img1.png/$3/" || exit 1 # overwrite the name of the first image
[[ -f "$4" ]] && sed "$2/document.fodp" "s/img2.png/$4/" || exit 1 # overwrite the name of the second image
[[ -f "$5" ]] && sed "$2/document.fodp" "s/img3.png/$5/" || exit 1 # overwrite the name of the third image
```

This script should be invoked this way :

`insertImages.sh "/path/to/the/template.fodp" "/path/to/the/document" "image1.png" "image2.png" "image3.png"`

I'm not a big programmer. So there is probably some mistakes in those lines. But the principle is there.

They are some constaints :

- a flat document
- relative pathes to the images.

Comment: Thanks! This is an old question.. will try and let you know.